# Storing and reading an NLTK Chunk Tree in a file

Tags: nltk, tagged-corpus

I have an NLTK tree object where there exist 6 NP chunks.

```
t1 = Tree('S', [('现在', 'T'), ('每', 'RZ'), ('次', 'QV'), ('打火', 'VN'), ('比较', 'D'), ('反感', 'V'), Tree('NP', [('悦动', 'NZ')]), Tree('NP', [('打火', 'VI'), ('时', 'TG'), ('比较', 'D'), ('嘈杂', 'A'), ('的', 'UDE1'), ('声音', 'N')]), ('，', 'WD'), ('当然', 'D'), Tree('NP', [('比', 'P')]), Tree('NP', [('面包车', 'N')]), Tree('NP', [('打火', 'VI'), ('的', 'UDE1'), ('声音', 'N')]), Tree('NP', [('算是', 'V'), ('好听', 'A'), ('的', 'UDE1')]), ('！', 'WT')])
```

and I want to have this `t1` saved in hard disk, so I write it into a file like below.

```
>>> print(t1)
(S
    现在/T
    每/RZ
    次/QV
    打火/VN
    比较/D
    反感/V
    (NP 悦动/NZ)
    (NP 打火/VI 时/TG 比较/D 嘈杂/A 的/UDE1 声音/N)
    ，/WD
    当然/D
    (NP 比/P)
    (NP 面包车/N)
    (NP 打火/VI 的/UDE1 声音/N)
    (NP 算是/V 好听/A 的/UDE1)
    ！/WT)
>>> file.write(t1.__str__())
```

Having `t1` saved in a file, I've tried to reload it from a file with [BracketParseCorpusReader](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=bracketparsecorpusreader#nltk.corpus.reader.bracket_parse.BracketParseCorpusReader), but It didn't work very well.

```
# nltk.corpus.__init__.py
bracket2 = LazyCorpusLoader(
'Bracket2', BracketParseCorpusReader, r'car/.*\.txt', encoding='utf8') 

>>> bracket2.tagged_words()  # Bracket2 is a instance of BracketParseCorpusReader
[('悦动/NZ', 'NP'), ('比/P', 'NP'), ('面包车/N', 'NP'), ...]
# failed to load words other than NP chunk

>>> bracket2.tagged_words()[0]
('悦动/NZ', 'NP')
# failed to load the first word "现在/T"

>>> bracket2.tagged_sents()[0]
[('悦动/NZ', 'NP'), ('比/P', 'NP'), ('面包车/N', 'NP')]
# failed to load the whole sentence
```

The reader cannot tell word and tag. It seems to give some appropriate parameters regarding to POS seperator, sent_tokenizer, but I have no idea how to customize it.

- What NLTK Reader should I use to read `t1` above?
- Alternatively, Is there a way to save NLTK Tree object in a file, and retrieve it as the original structure?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to save a tree to file and then 'interpret' that tree later on again, right?

Using the tree.fromstring() might be the way to go:

```
import nltk
t = nltk.tree.Tree.fromstring("(S (NP (D the) (N dog)) (VP (V chased) (NP (D the) (N cat))))")
```

It does exactly what the name suggest ;).

See also http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tree.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Igor, but I actually wanted to read the string form of the Tree with `nltk.reader`. I bypassed by using `tree2conllstr` to write it into the file, and loading it by `ConllChunkedCorpusReader`.